# Using java 8 steam to find matching rows between two list and map to another object

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I am trying to find matching element between two different lists and then I am trying to map to list of different object which contains the elements from both the list some selected elements.

Here are my two beans -

```
public class LogsData {
    LocalDate eventDate ;
    String correlationId;
    String authId;
    int numberofSQL;
    // getter and setter
}
```

```
public class DistributionData {
    LocalDate eventDate;
    String correlationId;
    String callingProId;
    long transactionCount ;
    // getter and setter 
}
```

```
public class ResultBean {
    LocalDate eventDate;
    String correlationId;
    String callingProId;
    long transactionCount ;
    String authId ;
    int numberOfSQL;
}
```

How do I get a final list which contains a match with `correlationId` , `eventDate` and in the result, I wanted List of `ResultBean`.

Can somebody please assist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be _much_ easier if you don't bother using streams.

Comment: Can be more than one element with the same (eventDate, correlationId) in logs data list? Same for distribution data list. If yes, if there are i.e. 2 duplicates in the logs list and 3 duplicates in the distribution list, all with the same (eventDate, correlationId) through both lists, do you expect the result to contain all the possible combinations, i.e. 6 elements?

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to accumulate the elements of the `logsData` list into a map where the key is `logsData#getEventDate` concatenated with `logsData#getCorrelationId`.

```
Map<String, LogsData> accumulator = 
        logsData.stream()
                .collect(toMap(l -> l.getEventDate() + l.getCorrelationId(), Function.identity()));
```

then stream over the `distributionData` list and get the corresponding elements in the map and then transform them into a `ResultBean`.

```
List<ResultBean> resultSet = distributionData.stream()
       .map(d -> {
              LogsData logs = accumulator.get(d.getEventDate() + d.getCorrelationId());
              if (logs != null)
                   return new ResultBean(d.getEventDate(), d.getCorrelationId(),
                     d.getCallingProId(), d.getTransactionCount(), logs.getAuthId(), logs.getNumberofSQL());
                 return null;
       })
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this assumes `ResultBean` has a constructor taking all the necessary arguments if that's not the case then just call the setter methods to set the necessary data.

imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;
```

another approach although less efficient:

```
List<ResultBean> resultSet = logsData.stream()
                .map(l -> distributionData.stream()
                        .filter(d -> l.getEventDate().equals(d.getEventDate()) &&
                                l.getCorrelationId().equals(d.getCorrelationId()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(d -> new ResultBean(d.getEventDate(), d.getCorrelationId(),
                                d.getCallingProId(), d.getTransactionCount(), l.getAuthId(), l.getNumberofSQL()))
                        .orElse(null))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

slightly different, in JDK9 in avoiding the `.orElse(null)).filter(Objects::nonNull)` pattern:

```
List<ResultBean> resultSet = logsData.stream()
                .flatMap(l -> distributionData.stream()
                        .filter(d -> l.getEventDate().equals(d.getEventDate()) &&
                                l.getCorrelationId().equals(d.getCorrelationId()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(d -> new ResultBean(d.getEventDate(), d.getCorrelationId(),
                                d.getCallingProId(), d.getTransactionCount(), l.getAuthId(), l.getNumberofSQL()))
                        .stream()
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [Louis Wasserman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798373/using-java-8-steam-to-find-matching-rows-between-two-list-and-map-to-another-obj#comment92516669_52798373) it might be possible to use Streams where it has an advantage.
Consider having `LogsData` and `DistributionData` (and optionally `ResultBean`) extend a base type:

```
class Data {

    LocalDate eventDate ;
    String correlationId;

    Data(LocalDate eventDate, String correlationId) {
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
    }

    LocalDate getEventDate() { return eventDate; }
    String getCorrelationId(){ return correlationId; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof Data)) { return false; }
        Data d = (Data) o;
        return eventDate.equals(d.getEventDate())
                && correlationId.equals(d.getCorrelationId() );
    }
}
```

Given to list :

```
List<LogsData> logsData = new ArrayList<>();
List<DistributionData> dData = new ArrayList<>();
```

You could intersect two lists simply by

```
logsData.retainAll(dData);
dData.retainAll(logsData);
```

Have them sorted at the same order :

```
//sort so two lists have the same order. If correlationId is not unique you may need 
//to enhance the comperator 
Collections.sort(dData, (a, b) -> a.getCorrelationId().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getCorrelationId()));
Collections.sort(logsData, (a, b) -> a.getCorrelationId().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getCorrelationId()));
```

and use `Stream` to construct a List of `ResultBean` objects:

```
List<ResultBean> resultList = IntStream.range(0, logsData.size())
    .mapToObj( i ->
            new ResultBean(dData.get(i).getEventDate(), dData.get(i).getCorrelationId(),
            dData.get(i).getCallingProId(), dData.get(i).getTransactionCount(),
            logsData.get(i).getAuthId(), logsData.get(i).getNumberofSQL())
            )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed little bit design to make it to work , I added Distribution List into Logs Beans as it has one to many relationship ,  i am able to combine data from both list but it is running very slow as the collection size is quite large especially the Distribution list , can somebody please suggest something highly performant or any better design .

```
 List<LogsData> logsData = logs.stream()
            .filter(e -> (distributionData.stream()
                    .filter(d -> 
           d.getCorrelationId.equals(e.getCorrelationId))
       .filter(d-> d.getEventDate().equals(e.getEventDate()))
       .map(mapper-> e.getDistribution().add(mapper); return e; })
                    .count())<1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach (although you didn't specify if there can be duplicates in the lists)

You could create a ResultKey object:

```
record ResultKey(
    LocalDate eventDate,   
    String correlationId
) {}
```

And use it for grouping:

```
Map<ResultKey, List<LogsData>> logsMap = logsData.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> new ResultKey(it.eventDate, it.correlationId)));

Map<ResultKey, List<DistributionData>> distributionMap = distributionData.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> new ResultKey(it.eventDate, it.correlationId)));
```

Having two maps with unified keys, you could do intersection for keeping keys that are in both maps:

```
Set<ResultKey> intersection = new HashSet<>(logsMap.keySet());
intersection.retainAll(distributionMap.keySet());
```

And finally do the mapping:

```
        List<ResultBean> resultBeans = intersection.stream()
                .map(key -> {
                    var log = logsMap.get(key).stream().findFirst().get();
                    var distribution = distributionMap.get(key).stream().findFirst().get();
                    return new ResultBean(key.eventDate, key.correlationId, distribution.callingProId,
                            distribution.transactionCount, log.authId, log.numberofSQL);
                }).toList();
```